# Angular Routing with Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

Right now I have a simple Angular project set up with Express serving my index.html file. Later on in the project, I realized I needed a landing page that needs some of the functionality (form input that makes an API call) of index.html file. How would I go about Express taking care of my routes? Do I need to change it so my landing page is served from express? Also, if the above is true, would it be good practice to rename the landing page to 'index.html' and have the main page renamed to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can split your site up however you want, the point of angular really is for building single page applications. This means that usually you would combine your landing page with the rest of your site into a single angular project. Then you would handle your routing inside angular. For example:

```
yourdomain.com/#/landing - landing page
yourdomain.com/#/home - some other part of your site
```

By doing this, you end up just serving your entire project from `index.html` like you are currently doing, and you also don't have to duplicate any of your project code.

---

If you are familiar with angular routing, that's great, but if not, I prefer ui-router over the standard routing library: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router